# Is there a system suspend event in AIR?

Tags: events, air

Can an Adobe AIR application detect when the host system is put to sleep/suspend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the [userIdle](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html#event%3auserIdle) event from the [flash.desktop.NativeApplication](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html) class.

you may also prevent the system from becoming idle by setting the [systemIdleMode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html#systemIdleMode) property:

```
//Prevent
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE;

//Allow
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.NORMAL;
```

if neither of those options suit your needs, you can always use [NativeProcess](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html) to handle  processes on the host operating system.

Comment: NativeApplication has a timeSinceLastUserInput property which can be used to calculate when the system was suspended. I.e. if you get a userIdle event and the timeSinceLastUserInput is greater than the idleThreshold, then you can infer that the system has just woken up from suspend.